# react native - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobile/com.mobile.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url: http://

Tags: android, react-native

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.
- I'm trying to "react-native run-android" my app. 
- File structure created by "react-native init"
- **Works fine with the emulators, when I try to push to a usb-connected device**.
- The build is successful, the apk gets installed and then it crashes right away.

The error from the device log:

```
11-20 18:16:28.513 18430 18430 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobile/com.mobile.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url: http://
11-20 18:16:28.513 18430 18430 E AndroidRuntime: 
11-20 18:16:28.513 18430 18430 E AndroidRuntime: 
11-20 18:16:28.513 18430 18430 E AndroidRuntime: 192.168.2.74/status
```

**I'm not sure where that ip comes from it doesnt match the servers or the phones.**

The exception is thrown by the Okhttp request builder:

```
public Builder url(String url) {
      if (url == null) throw new NullPointerException("url == null");

      // Silently replace web socket URLs with HTTP URLs.
      if (url.regionMatches(true, 0, "ws:", 0, 3)) {
        url = "http:" + url.substring(3);
      } else if (url.regionMatches(true, 0, "wss:", 0, 4)) {
        url = "https:" + url.substring(4);
      }

      HttpUrl parsed = HttpUrl.parse(url);
      if (parsed == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected url: " + url);
      return url(parsed);
    }
```

My mainActivity:

```
package com.mobile;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "mobile";
    }

}
```

MainApplication:

```
package com.mobile;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.transistorsoft.rnbackgroundgeolocation.RNBackgroundGeolocation;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
        return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new CodePush(getResources().getString(R.string.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey), getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG),
            new RNBackgroundGeolocation(),
            new VectorIconsPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Any thoughts? I bolded what I think are my best clues.

UPDATE: 
I've tried commenting out all my external libs, including codepush, just to close in on it... Im still getting the same results.

UPDATE: 
Also made a brand new project w/ rn init. I built it and sent it to the device just fine, no crash. So ADB and all that stuff seem to be working OK.

Answer (score 1):

After two days of sheer frustration.

The answer: Do not name your project 'mobile'.

ya...